# Second annotated aspect not being called

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm trying to get my head around Spring AOP and currently are facing the issue, that the second aspect annotated by `TrackedSubTask` is not being called, while the `Tracked` works.
Any help or clue is appreciated.

Here are my annotated classes:

```
@RestController
public class Demo {
    @Tracked
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        DemoImpl bar = new DemoImpl();
        bar.foo();
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}

public class DemoImpl{
    @TrackedSubTask
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Here are my annotations:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Tracked  {
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrackedSubTask {
}
```

Here are my aspects:

```
@Aspect
@Component
class MyAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(annotation)")
    public Object first(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Tracked annotation) throws Throwable {
        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        return proceed;
    }

    @Around("@annotation(subTaskAnnotation)")
    public Object second(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, TrackedSubTask subTaskAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        Object  proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        return proceed;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DemoImpl` isn't managed by spring as you are creating a new instance yourself.

Comment: Thanks! That was is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M. Deinum correctly pointed out, the `DemoImpl` needed to be managed by Spring.